# How to fill an array using another array's IDs in Golang

Tags: mysql, arrays, go, go-gorm

So i want to get all commPlans from IDs inside comms but for some reason i only get one object(which is the first ID in comms).
Here is my code:

```
comms := models.GetComms(CommID)
if comms == nil {
    componentsJson.WriteError(ctx, componentsError.ERROR_PARAMETERS_INVALID)
    return
}

var commPlans []models.CommPlan
for _, comm := range comms {
    commPlans = models.GetCommPlans(comm.CommPlanID)
}
if commPlans == nil {
    componentsJson.WriteError(ctx, componentsError.ERROR_PARAMETERS_INVALID)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `append` the result from `GetCommPlans` to the `commPlans` slice, right now you're overwriting any previously returned result.

Either do:

```
comms := models.GetComms(CommID)
if comms == nil {
    componentsJson.WriteError(ctx, componentsError.ERROR_PARAMETERS_INVALID)
    return
}

// a slice of slices
var commPlans [][]models.CommPlan
for _, comm := range comms {
    commPlans = append(commPlans, models.GetCommPlans(comm.CommPlanID))
}
if commPlans == nil {
    componentsJson.WriteError(ctx, componentsError.ERROR_PARAMETERS_INVALID)
    return
}
```

Or:

```
comms := models.GetComms(CommID)
if comms == nil {
    componentsJson.WriteError(ctx, componentsError.ERROR_PARAMETERS_INVALID)
    return
}

var commPlans []models.CommPlan
for _, comm := range comms {
    commPlans = append(commPlans, models.GetCommPlans(comm.CommPlanID)...)
}
if commPlans == nil {
    componentsJson.WriteError(ctx, componentsError.ERROR_PARAMETERS_INVALID)
    return
}
```

Comment: Oh i see...Thanks!